# Treat part of a Regex expression as non-special characters

Tags: notepad++, regex, escape-characters

Let's say I've got a regex expression utilizing some of the special chars, but also a portion with 'normal' text that just happens to have some symbols in. Let's also say I'm too lazy to start escaping every "would-be" special character in the 'normal text' part.

How can I enclose the 'normal' text bit so that Regex doesn't start throwing a fit when it thinks it's come across a special character (when really it hasn't) ?

As an example, let's say I search for the text:

`.*Hello it's true that ([6*.5]^2=9)`.

I certainly don't want to laboriously use the escape char each time any of the special chars appears in that maths section (or the apostrophe in "don't"). On the other hand, I DO want to treat the `.*` bit at the start as special characters.

So can I enclose the `Hello it's true that ([6*.5]^2=9)` section so that Regex treats it as normal text and not special?

I'm using Notepad++ to do a find and replace, but hopefully, any answer will be the same no matter what the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `\Q` to start a literal, and end with `\E`.

This works with many flavours of Regex, though Java may have problems for instance.

Information obtained from: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Comment: I take sites such as those cautiously.  [Notepad++ 6 release notes](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.0-release.html) would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Some tools allow you to change whether special characters must be escaped by default.  For instance, `vi` (and clones) has a `magic` mode which controls this.  That can let you reduce the amount of escaping needed.

Comment: Wow, so there's nothing in the default spec? Just this one thing alone makes me hate Regex more than anything else that might otherwise be wrong with it.

Comment: Someone might recall a different case.  The vi "magic" feature by the way is reflected in the differences between BREs and EREs (grep vs egrep), etc.

Comment: I found out that it is possible with most flavours of Regex after all. Bitterness starting to fade... :) See my own answer to this Q.

Comment: Not exactly: it is the Perl-derived flavor which pcre provides, and recent versions of Notepad++ use.  POSIX regex's don't do that (though there may be some aspect which I'm overlooking).  Perl is not POSIX, of course.